# @ (at sign) in Drupal strings

Tags: drupal

In another question, someone posted this code in an answer to my question.

```
drupal_set_message(
  t('Some Message @title'), array('@title' => $form_state['values']['title']))
);
```

It looks to me that the "@title" is substituted with `$form_state['values']['title']`.

What is this called and what are the advantages and disadvantage of it?

From a quick look, I see that *@* is used for error suppression, but this is reported in a PHP 4.3 book I have, rather than PHP 5.

Comment: it's something drupal related, not PHP

Comment: Drupal lack documentation in many places. But certainly not for the bases API functions such as t(). Before asking such question about a function, you could check its documentation. In this case, see http://api.drupal.org/api/function/t/6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Drupal, an `@` sign in front of a placeholder is used to signal to Drupal's string parser to run the string attached to the placeholder through [`check_plain()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/check_plain).

More info about string placeholders can be found on the [`t()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/t) API page.