# What does @ mean in a string PHP? (Not the error suppression operator)

Tags: php, drupal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@ (at sign) in drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674689/at-sign-in-drupal)

I know that sometimes it has to do with error suppression but I'm looking at Drupal code and I can't recognize the syntax:

Example 1:

```
$batch = array(
'operations' => $operations,
'finished' => '_install_profile_batch_finished',
'title' => st('Installing @drupal', array('@drupal' => drupal_install_profile_name())),
'error_message' => st('The installation has encountered an error.'),
);
```

Example 2:

```
drupal_set_title(st('@drupal installation complete', array('@drupal' => drupal_install_profile_name())));
```

Example 3:

```
$output .= '<p>'. (isset($messages['error']) ? st('Please review the messages above before continuing on to <a href="@url">your new site</a>.', array('@url' => url(''))) : st('You may now visit <a href="@url">your new site</a>.', array('@url' => url('')))) .'</p>';
```

Comment: I don't know where, but I am 100 % sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Stefano: I found a dupe - [@ (at sign) in drupal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674689/at-sign-in-drupal)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This hasn't to do with php, but with drupal. `@drupal` is a variable used by the templating engine drupal uses.

Answer (score 2):

This is Drupal specific, it means the variable is run through check_plain, which escapes HTML characters ([Relevant Drupal API documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/t/6)).

The t() and st() functions are used for translatable strings.

Answer (score 0):

It is part of the drupal template engine.  This is a flag for a replacement variable.

Comment: Not here. read the question first.

Comment: this is not right, please read the question.

Comment: How is that not right? Its essentially the same answer as yours with 8 upvotes. Drupal can use replacements.

Comment: the answer was edited after my comment and before your comment.